# Open Macro to remove KIll Excel.exe

Tags: vba, excel

I created an an Excel macro that works correctly however when I add this code to my macro in `PERSONAL.XLS` from the start directory of `MS Excel` (*in a bad place in the macro*), I can't open the macro and I can't find it..

How can I open the macro to delete this bad code!!!

```
Dim sKill As String
sKill ="TASKKILL /f /IM EXCEL.EXE"
....
shell sKill , vbHide
```

Answer (score 1):

... Why not just remove your personal.xls from that directory and start over??

OR Remove it, rename it as a.xls or anything else and then open it.

OR set your Tools > macro options so that the macros don't run.

Comment: Beleave me ; I tried to do all solution ; BUT, whe, I open the macro , I found an other one wich not contain my last macro .. I don't found the last macro that I created by my self in few minutes.
I found a macro for 1 month ago !!

Comment: How is that possible??? If you open your personal.xls, it will have to contain the macro that is running... Can you please update your question with more information, then?

Comment: Personal.xls should be for XP in 
`C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`
In Vista or Windows 7:
`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`

Comment: ...do a search of your C-drive for `Personal.xls` using windows explorer just to make sure you have all instances of it covered